# Opening daemon specific ports

Tags: linux, networking, unix-sockets

How can we set firewall inbound rules for specific daemon if it is using random port from range of Ephemeral ports? There is Custom Rule wizard available in Windows. Does LINUX and UNIX has similar functionality available to allow daemon specific inbound rule traffic? Thank you.

Comment: Does the daemon initiate the initial connection out or is it listening for inbound on a semi-random range?

Comment: Also is the daemon running under a specific user?

Comment: Can you give examples of traffic types of your daemon?

Comment: The daemon listening for inbound on a semi-random range. Installing user or root can run the it and it uses TCP connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the process id (pid) of you daemon you can quite easily write a script to modify your firewall rules dynamically. You didn't say what firewall you were using, or if it is a PERMIT ALL DENY, or a DENY ALL PERMIT ruleset, but here is a basic script that you can get some idea's from and build on.

This script starts a netcat listener on a random tcp port between 4000 and 5000.

```
nc -l $((RANDOM%1000+4000)) &
echo $!
sleep 2 #avoid bad way to avoid a race condition.
DYNAMICPORT=`netstat -lpdn | grep $! |  awk '{print $4}'`. 

echo $DYNAMICPORT
0.0.0.0:4078
```

you can then use $DYNAMICPORT to modify your firewall rules accordingly, on the FLY.

Bearing in mind when the process finishes to remove any rules that you added dynamically.

The problem with this solution is that it has to be ran periodically since the daemon use an ephermeral range of ports.

Problem #1 with this solution: you may face several race conditions between the time a port get opened/closed by the daemon and the time the script discovers it.

Problem #2: managing iptables ruleset dynamically from a script may lead to a total mess ..

Problem #3: If the daemon forks, and that fork open ports , then this script will fail

Problem #4: If the daemon continues to open listening ports ,then the script will need to be running constantly,  again, this is racey.

Problem #5: Keeping track of listening ports that are not longer listening and active will be tricky, making deletion of firewall rules impossible.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it has to be ran periodically since OP said his daemon use an *ephermeral* range of ports. Problem #1 with your solution: you may face several race conditions between the time a port get opened/closed by the daemon and the time your script discover it. Problem #2: managing iptables ruleset dynamically from a script may lead to a total mess ...

Answer (score 0):

Under my Debian Linux 10, `iptables` provides a `owner` module:

```
root@avalon:~# iptables -m owner --help |tail -n4
owner match options:
[!] --uid-owner userid[-userid]      Match local UID
[!] --gid-owner groupid[-groupid]    Match local GID
[!] --socket-exists                  Match if socket exists
root@avalon:~#
```

If you can deploy this service under a dedicated user, then you can probably achieve your needs.

Comment: Does this solution allow you to match an individual PID?

Comment: In the past, it does but the support of pid match [has been removed since it doesn't worked well](https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg49716.html). But, if OP can run his daemon using a dedicated user, it may be enought.